# Images for .NET buttons

Tags: image, button, standards

I have an application which will support several standard operations

- play
- stop
- pause
- undo

I'd like to have images for those buttons. I've been searching through vs2005 image library but the images there are non consistent. For example the play button (playhs.bmp) is green while stop (stophs.bmp) is blue.

Also I haven't found an undo image

what other common images bundles are there out there? Or is there something like an addon to vs2005 image library?
I'd like something free if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this thread on Joel of Software forum:

http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.755808.5

Lots of excellent free icons packs!

Answer (score 1):

This site should help you out:

http://www.minervity.com/features/icons-features/18-search-engines-for-designers-creativity-boost/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the free [Silk icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) set for small 16x16 icons.

Comment: I checked, and there are no consistent Stop/Play icons in that set.

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it Jamie.